# Make Group Chat Images into one avatar thumbnail

Tags: ios, swift3, swift2

How to achieve facebook messenger group chat imageView like this?? I am downloading the images using kingfisher for single image holding imageview in tableview cell.What is the best way to achieve group image for group of three and group of many (excluding the user)

[image]
[image]